# How do I give assumptions to Simplify or Solve?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I've have the expression:

```
q2sol = 
  (Sec[2*a1]*Tan[a1]^3*(-7 + 6*Cot[a1]^3*Sqrt[Tan[a1]^2]))/(6*Sqrt[Tan[a1]^2])
```

I know that `a1` is in $[0,\,\pi/4)$ (by design). Hence, I know that the factor `Sqrt[Tan[a1]^2]` can be simplified to `Tan[a1]`. How can I give a hint to Mathematica so I get a nice, fully automatic simplification?

Another similar question. When evaluating

```
s2at1equ = 
  (-6*(20 - 33*Cos[a0]*Sec[f]^3 + Cos[4*f]*(20 - 26*Cos[a0]*Sec[f]^3) + 
     Cos[2*f]*(-20 + 39*Cos[a0]*Sec[f]^3))) / 
  (7*f*Sqrt[f^2]*(1 - Cos[2*f] + Cos[4*f]))
s2at1res = Solve[s2at1equ == 0, {a0}, Reals]
```

I get many answers under some complex conditions, but I know that `f` is positive, and `a0` is to be found in $[0,\,\pi/4)$. How do I give assumptions to Mathematica to keep only the meaningful solutions?

Comment: Concerning the first question, `Simplify[(Sec[2*a1]*Tan[a1]^3*(-7 + 6*Cot[a1]^3*Sqrt[Tan[a1]^2]))/(6*
    Sqrt[Tan[a1]^2]), Assumptions -> a1 >= 0 && a1 <= Pi/4]` does the job.

Comment: Look up *assumptions* in the Documentation Center. Make sure  *assumptions* is all lowercase as shown.

Comment: @m_goldberg thank you for your remark, I try to look at the manual as much as I can however, the wolfram syntax being close to absolutely esoteric for me, even "reading the f*cking manual" didn't saved me here (hence this question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

q2sol = (Sec[2*a1]*Tan[a1]^3*(-7 + 6*Cot[a1]^3*Sqrt[Tan[a1]^2]))/(6*
     Sqrt[Tan[a1]^2]);
```

[`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) using the constraint as an assumption.

```
q2sol // Simplify[#, 0 <= a1 < Pi/4] &

(* 1/6 Sec[2 a1] (6 - 7 Tan[a1]^2) *)

s2at1equ = (-6*(20 - 33*Cos[a0]*Sec[f]^3 + 
       Cos[4*f]*(20 - 26*Cos[a0]*Sec[f]^3) + 
       Cos[2*f]*(-20 + 39*Cos[a0]*Sec[f]^3)))/(7*f*
     Sqrt[f^2]*(1 - Cos[2*f] + Cos[4*f]));
```

[`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) does not take the option [`Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html); however, `Solve` works on a system of equations or inequalities. Include the constraint in the system provided to `Solve`.

```
s2at1res = Assuming[0 <= a0 < Pi/4,
  Solve[{s2at1equ == 0, 0 <= a0 < Pi/4}, a0, Reals] // Simplify]
```

[image]

Verifying the solution,

```
s2at1equ == 0 /. s2at1res[[1]] // Simplify
```

[image]

The condition is extremely complicated. Any known constraints on `f` should also be included as an inequality constraint in the system.

Comment: Thank you all ! (and commenters) this answer is perfect ! I learned more than asked